# WPF Data Binding - Custom Format for TimeSpan Object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I would like to format the string for a TimeSpan object as the following example: 10h 12m 55s

How can I do this?

xaml

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding Path=ElapsedTime}"/>
```

xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    { 
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Streaming StreamingTest = new Streaming();
            DataContext = StreamingTest;
        }
    }

public class Streaming 
   {

   // code

    public TimeSpan ElapsedTime
        {
            get
            {
                return DateTime.Now - startTime;
            }
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `StringFormat={}{0:h}`. but `Timespan` format doesn't work like `Datetime`. You can achieve following way.

1. Convert Timespan to Datetime

```cs
DateTime newElapsedTime = new DateTime() + ElapsedTime;
```

Then use just like that

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=newElapsedTime, StringFormat={}{0:HH}h {0:mm}m {0:ss}s }" />
```

Or

2. Write your own Converter

```cs
public class TimeSpanFormatter:IValueConverter
    {        

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var ts=(TimeSpan)value;
            return string.Format("{0}h {1}m {2}s",ts.Hours,ts.Minutes,ts.Seconds);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Then use just like that. Declare formatter in Resource section with name `TimeSpanFormatter`.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ElapsedTime,Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanFormatter}}"></TextBlock>
```